# MySQL to MS Access

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

For some time we've been retrieving data from a remote MS Access database and copy its contents to a local Access DB with a simple SELECT * INTO query. However we're currently in a migration process which requires to retrieve data from the MySQL database and copy it to the local Access DB, thus the aforementioned query won't work here for obvious reasons.

Now seeing as I can't use any external programs and are only allowed to write in VB.NET, my method to transfer the data over is by using datatables. It does its job, but the performance is dreadful.

My questions therefore is, is there a fast way to transfer/copy data from the remote MySQL database to a local MS Access with only using VB.NET.

My current code: pastebin.com/ELmkVFSc

Comment: Add the MySQL table as a linked table and query it probably the same way your doing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very roughly:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dbEng As New DBEngine()
        Dim ws As Workspace
        Dim db As Database
        ws = dbEng.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", WorkspaceTypeEnum.dbUseJet)
        db = ws.OpenDatabase("z:\\docs\\test.accdb", False, False, "")
        db.Execute("SELECT * INTO Newtable From [ODBC;DSN=MySQL;].test")

    End Sub

End Module
```

You could also have a query on these lines:

```
SELECT * INTO Newtable FROM
[ODBC;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test;User=usr;Password=pwd;CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS;Option=3;].test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the client PC's do not have the necessary ODBC drivers installed and the IT admin is not willing to install it either. Is there an other way to this? Without using ODBC.

Comment: Even with linked tables you need drivers. How are you creating the datatables? What is the outline of your connection string? I guess you could write out a csv from MySQL and run a Microsoft text driver against that to import into Access.

Comment: It looks like you are using the MySQL Net Connector. If IT are prepared to install that, why not an ODBC driver from the same source? Odd. I am not sure I can help you further other than to say that output to CSV and import to MS Access will be a lot faster than walking a recordset.

Comment: Nevermind that, it seems that I was misinformed and the drivers are indeed installed. Your solution works. Thank you.