# Copy records from Access to SQL

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

Is there a faster way to copy records from an Access database to a SQL database?

At the moment I'm retrieving one record at a time and inserting it into SQL but this takes a long time. I know there is "SELECT INTO tbl_name" but as far as I can tell this is only useful when the query is being in the 'sending' database (in this case the Access db).

My current code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['odbc_connect'])){
$odbc_conn = $_POST['odbc_connect'];
}else{
exit ($noODBC);
}
$conn=odbc_connect($odbc_conn,'','') or die ($errorODBC);
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$odbcServer = $shell->RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\JuniorDSN\\DBQ");

$sql="SELECT * FROM [Cost Centre Hierarchy]";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql); 

// Connect to your database
mysql_select_db($database_budgetstatementconnection, $budgetstatementconnection);

// Delete contents of table
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE tblcostcentrehierarchy";
mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
// Retrieve the record from Junior
$strCostCentre = odbc_result($rs,1);
$strCCDescription = odbc_result($rs,2);
$enabled = odbc_result($rs,3);
$path = odbc_result($rs,4);
$level1 = odbc_result($rs,5);
$level2 = odbc_result($rs,6);
$level3 = odbc_result($rs,7);
$level4 = odbc_result($rs,8);
$level5 = odbc_result($rs,9);
$level6 = odbc_result($rs,10);
$level7 = odbc_result($rs,11);
$level8 = odbc_result($rs,12);

// Parse the data
$strCCDescription = str_replace("'","\'",$strCCDescription);
$strCCDescription = str_replace('"',"",$strCCDescription);
$level1 = str_replace("'","\'",$level1);
$level1 = str_replace('"',"",$level1);
$level2 = str_replace("'","\'",$level2);
$level2 = str_replace('"',"",$level2);
$level3 = str_replace("'","\'",$level3);
$level3 = str_replace('"',"",$level3);
$level4 = str_replace("'","\'",$level4);
$level4 = str_replace('"',"",$level4);
$level5 = str_replace("'","\'",$level5);
$level5 = str_replace('"',"",$level5);
$level6 = str_replace("'","\'",$level6);
$level6 = str_replace('"',"",$level6);
$level7 = str_replace("'","\'",$level7);
$level7 = str_replace('"',"",$level7);
$level8 = str_replace("'","\'",$level8);
$level8 = str_replace('"',"",$level8);
$level8 = trim(preg_replace('/\n\r|\r\n/', "", $level8 ));

 // Save the record to the database
 $sql = "insert into `budgetstatements`.`tblcostcentrehierarchy` (`CostCentreCode`, `CostCentreDescription`, `Enabled`, `Path`, `Level1`, `Level2`, `Level3`, `Level4`, `Level5`, `Level6`, `Level7`, `Level8`) values ('".$strCostCentre."', '".$strCCDescription."', '".$enabled."', '".$path."', '".$level1."', '".$level2."', '".$level3."', '".$level4."', '".$level5."', '".$level6."', '".$level7."', '".$level8."')";

// Execute the sql
mysql_query($sql);

}

//Close the connections
odbc_close($conn);
mysql_close($budgetstatementconnection);
```

Comment: Do you have to do it only once? If so, then why not export your complete table and then import in mysql (manually)

Comment: @Hanky Panky - no it's a regular refresh

Comment: You can link MySql tables and update them with a regular query in MS Acccess. You cam also refer to the MySQL table in-line against an MS Access connection. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591809/mysql-to-ms-access/12592970#12592970 -- it will also work from MySQL to Access.

Comment: To be able to give more specific help, which version of Access and which SQL server (MS< Oracle, MySQL, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `SELECT INTO tbl_name` is used to create a new table, as your table already exists in the SQL database you can link to it; have a read of this page on [How to link tables in an Access project by using the Link Table Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/link-tables-in-an-access-project-by-using-the-link-table-wizard-adp-HP003089371.aspx).

Once the table in your SQL database is linked to the Access database you can issue the SQL statement against the Access database, it will treat the linked table as though it exists within the same database:

```
INSERT INTO [tblcostcentrehierarchy] -- linked table name
SELECT * FROM [Cost Centre Hierarchy] -- local Access table
```

Assuming your field names are the same. If the field names are different, or in a different order, you will need to specify them in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Is that the SQL query or the ODBC query.I tried $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO [tblcostcentrehierarchy] SELECT * FROM [Cost Centre Hierarchy]"; but it didn't work. How does it know which db [Cost Centre Hierarchy] is in?

Comment: The query would be executed against the Access database. It only needs the linked table name in the query (it will know the destination DB from the linked table information). Search on 'linked table manager' for your version of Access.

Comment: I was hoping to pull the data from Access but I guess I can get the Access db administrator to push the data to SQL. I searched for linked table manager and I think I've worked it out. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm glad you've managed to get it working. If you have the ability to execute a statement on the Access database you should not need the DBA to do it. It can even be saved as a query in Access which you then open.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to do this manually, you can take a look at [Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php).